# doctrine ODM (mongodb) merge doesn't work

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine, doctrine-odm

I'm not having any luck using `merge()`. I'm doing almost exactly [what is documented](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#merging-documents):

```
/* @var $detachedDocument MyDocumentClass */ 
$detachedDocument = unserialize($serializedDocument);
$document = $dm->merge($detachedDocument);
$document->setLastUpdated(new \MongoDate());
$dm->persist($document);
```

but the change never sticks. I have to do this instead:

```
$dm->createQueryBuilder('MyDocumentClass')
    ->findAndUpdate()
    ->field('lastUpdated')->set(new \MongoDate())
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```

`merge()` seems pretty straightforward, so I'm confused why it doesn't work like I think it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first code example, `merge()` followed by `persist()` is redundant, and you omitted a `flush()`, which is the only operation that would actually write to the database (unless you execute a query manually, as you did in the second example). If you walk through the code in `UnitOfWork::doMerge()`, you'll see that it's going to either persist the object (if it has no ID) or fetch the document by its ID. The end result is that `merge()` returns a managed document. Persist ensures that the document will be managed after it is called (it returns nothing itself). If you poke in `UnitOfWork::doPersist()`, you'll see that passing a managed object to the method is effectively a NOOP.

Try replacing `persist()` with `flush()`. Note that you can flush a single document if necessary, but `$dm->flush()` processes all managed objects by default.

If that still doesn't help, I'd confirm that the `lastUpdated` field is properly mapped in ODM. You can inspect the output of `$dm->getClassMetadata('MyDocumentClass')` to confirm. If it isn't a mapped field, UnitOfWork will detect no changes in the document and there will be nothing to flush.

As an aside: in the second code example, you're executing `findAndUpdate()` without any search criteria (only the `set()` is specified). Typically, you'd pair the modification with something like `equals()` (probably the ID in your case) to ensure that a single document is atomically modified and returned.

Comment: Thank you for this awesome answer! I'd upvote it twice if possible. I finally understand `flush()` and `merge()`. Good call about `equals()` , too. I forgot to include that in my contrived example.